# How to debug browser crash when running Silverlight app

Tags: silverlight, debugging, internet-explorer, crash

I am on a team of three people who are developing a Silverlight application. On two of our developers' machines the app seems to randomly crash. It never crashes on the third developer's machine.

The nature of the crash is that internet explorer just dies with an "Internet Explorer has stopped working" message. The problem details look like this:

```
  Problem Event Name:   BEX
  Application Name: IEXPLORE.EXE
  Application Version:  8.0.6001.18882
  Application Timestamp:    4b3ed243
  Fault Module Name:    StackHash_2cd8
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   00000000
  Exception Offset: 0024df00
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Data:   00000008
  OS Version:   6.0.6002.2.2.0.256.6
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 2cd8
  Additional Information 2: 0c337fa6c2057a9dbce1860c5e2d8315
  Additional Information 3: e13b
  Additional Information 4: 5da012709e52526a1af19795dc4a33fd
```

Then windows displays this message: "To help protect your computer, Data Execution Prevention has closed Internet Explorer."

If I am attached to the app with the Visual Studio debugger the only information I get is this line in the output window: "The program '[2140] iexplore.exe: Silverlight' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005)."

How should I go about debugging this problem? I'm not really sure where to start.

Comment: One of our team members is also facing this problem (in SL4). SL4 Beta worked fine, but after installing the full SL4, all browsers (IE, FF, Chrome) crash on pages with SL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the two developers who had the crash had a slightly older version of Silverlight on their machines. We now specify the minRuntimeVersion of Silverlight to the newer version and the problem has gone away.

Answer (score 0):

Is this Silverlight 4?  We were seeing this problem in earlier builds of Silverlight 4, but it seems to be cleared up with the RC release.